# C++ MFC overriden OnPaint() not painting on another computer

Tags: c++, mfc

I added code to OnPaint() and it paints correctly on my Windows 10 laptop, but the painting is not shown on another computer (Windows 8).  I'm a novice at painting and I probably did something wrong - maybe with invalidate and updatewindow.  Regardless, here is my code:

I am painting on a dialog window; the code for OnPaint() is mostly created by Visual Studios - I simply added DrawValveImage() at the end.  Also, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuSVZ.png) is picture that shows what DrawValveImage() draws.  I don't think you need to look at all the code for DrawValveImage() to solve the problem; I think my error is my placement of the calling of DrawValveImage().  Maybe OnPaint() isn't the right event for custom painting.

```
void CCleaningAndScreeningDlg::OnPaint()

{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);


    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }

    DrawValveImage();

}

void CCleaningAndScreeningDlg::DrawValveImage()
{
    //my own drawing
    CClientDC* pDC = new CClientDC(this);
    pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    COLORREF blueBorder = RGB(67, 99, 155);
    COLORREF blueFill = RGB(218, 227, 243);

    int x1 = 1050;
    int y1 = 50;
    int width = 300;
    int x2 = x1 + width;
    int y2 = y1 + width;


    CPen pen;
    CBrush brush;
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, blueBorder);
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(blueFill);

    // select brush and pen
    pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
    pDC->SelectObject(&brush);

    if (valveImageDrawn == FALSE)
        pDC->Ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    DeleteObject(brush);
    DeleteObject(pen);
    DeleteObject(&brush);
    DeleteObject(&pen);


    int heightWidth = width;
    int smallHeightWidth = heightWidth / 7;
    int radiusFromOriginSmallCircle = heightWidth / 2.75;

    for (int circleIndex = 0; circleIndex < 10; circleIndex++) {
        POINT centerSmallCircle = FindPointOnCircle(POINT{ heightWidth / 2, heightWidth / 2 }, radiusFromOriginSmallCircle, (circleIndex * 360 / 10) - 90);
        int smallCircleX = centerSmallCircle.x - smallHeightWidth / 2 + x1;
        int smallCircleY = centerSmallCircle.y - smallHeightWidth / 2 + y1;
        rectangle smallCircleRect = { smallCircleX, smallCircleY, smallCircleX + smallHeightWidth, smallCircleY + smallHeightWidth };
        rectsSmallCircles[circleIndex] = smallCircleRect;

        bool greenFilled = false;
        if (valvePosition - 1 == circleIndex) {
            CPen pen;
            CBrush brush;
            COLORREF greenFill = RGB(181, 230, 29);
            pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, blueBorder);
            brush.CreateSolidBrush(greenFill);
            pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
            pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
            pDC->Ellipse(smallCircleRect.x1, smallCircleRect.y1, smallCircleRect.x2, smallCircleRect.y2);

            DeleteObject(brush);
            DeleteObject(pen);
            DeleteObject(&brush);
            DeleteObject(&pen);

            greenFilled = true; //if mouse clicked and green color is painted on the valve image
        }
        else {
            CPen pen;
            CBrush brush;
            pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, blueBorder);
            brush.CreateSolidBrush(blueFill);
            pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
            pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
            pDC->Ellipse(smallCircleRect.x1, smallCircleRect.y1, smallCircleRect.x2, smallCircleRect.y2);

            DeleteObject(brush);
            DeleteObject(pen);
            DeleteObject(&brush);
            DeleteObject(&pen);     
        }

        CString circleText;
        int CircleNumber = circleIndex + 1;
        circleText.Format(_T("%d"), CircleNumber);


        CRect testRect = { smallCircleRect.x1,
            smallCircleRect.y1, smallCircleRect.x2, smallCircleRect.y2 };
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

        CClientDC dc(this);
        CFont font;
        VERIFY(font.CreateFont(
            30,                        // nHeight
            0,                         // nWidth
            0,                         // nEscapement
            0,                         // nOrientation
            FW_BOLD,                 // nWeight
            FALSE,                     // bItalic
            FALSE,                     // bUnderline
            0,                         // cStrikeOut
            ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
            OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
            DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
            DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
            _T("Arial")));                 // lpszFacename
        CFont* def_font = pDC->SelectObject(&font);
        pDC->DrawText(circleText, testRect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER | DT_CENTER);
        pDC->SelectObject(def_font);
        font.DeleteObject();



    }

    //redraw the combobox infront of the valve-image
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    comboPorts.Invalidate();
    comboPorts.UpdateWindow();

    valveImageDrawn = true;
}
```

Comment: Please read [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/device-contexts) and investigate how the MFC classes correlate. There's just too much wrong with the code, most notably a DC leak in `DrawValveImage`.

Comment: Could you tell me what to code?  I don't wish to read too much documentation - I don't understand it all.

Comment: Pretty much *all* of the code is wrong. Like deleting resources, while they are still selected into a DC, constructing multiple DC's, not deleting a DC, not passing on the `CPaintDC`. I'm afraid, you are going to have to read the documentation to proficiently use MFC. MFC is *very* complex. The fact that you do not understand the Windows API reduces your chances of grasping MFC down to zero.

Answer (score 4):

`OnPaint()` is the right method to do custom painting. When you override `OnPaint()`, you should *not* call the `OnPaint()` method of the base class. You are responsible to draw *all* of the content of the window on your own (except child windows).

You only need this code:

```
void CCleaningAndScreeningDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // constructor of CPaintDC calls ::BeginPaint()

    DrawValveImage( dc );  // pass device context to the drawing function

    // Destructor of CPaintDC automatically calls ::EndPaint()!
}
```

You can see that I have added a parameter to `DrawValveImage`. The declaration would look like this:

```
void DrawValveImage( CDC& dc );
```

Make sure that in your drawing function, you only use the `dc` parameter for drawing.

This is **wrong**:

> ```
> CClientDC* pDC = new CClientDC(this);
> ```

You should not create any additional device contexts.

Example of another mistake:

> ```
> pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
> pDC->SelectObject(&brush);
>
> if (valveImageDrawn == FALSE)
>     pDC->Ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
>
> DeleteObject(brush);
> DeleteObject(pen);
> DeleteObject(&brush);
> DeleteObject(&pen);
> ```

First, you don't restore the original state of the device context before you delete objects selected into it. When an object is still selected into a device context, it cannot be deleted correctly. To fix that, store the return value of `SelectObject()` and `SelectStockObject()`, which is a pointer to the object previously selected in the device context (if you didn't select one, there is a default object). Before you delete the object, call `SelectObject()`, passing the stored pointer.

Second, why do you delete objects twice? Either let the object destroy itself automatically when it leaves the current scope or call the `DeleteObject()` *member* function (rarely needed).

Corrected code:

```
auto pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&pen);
auto pOldBrush = dc.SelectObject(&brush);

if (valveImageDrawn == FALSE)
    dc.Ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);

if(pOldPen) 
    dc.SelectObject(pOldPen);
if(pOldBrush) 
    dc.SelectObject(pOldBrush );

// No need for DeleteObject(), the destructor of each object will delete it at the
// end of the current scope (before the function returns). But if you actually need it
// (say you want to reuse the variable), it would look like this:
// pen.DeleteObject();
// brush.DeleteObject();
```

This code is unnecessary:

> ```
> //redraw the combobox infront of the valve-image
> UpdateData(TRUE);
> comboPorts.Invalidate();
> comboPorts.UpdateWindow();
> ```

Just set the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style of the dialog window (using the dialog editor) to prevent the painting code from drawing over the combo box.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another question. I call DrawValveImage() in other parts of my code (e.g. after a left mouse button click). Is the following code okay?

CPaintDC dc(this);
DrawValveImage(dc);

I think it may be wrong because I'm not calling EndPaint().  Maybe this is a DC leak?

Comment: @DennisGahm In this case, you don't call `DrawValveImage` directly. Just call [`Invalidate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970.aspx) or [`InvalidateRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f3csed3.aspx) to indicate which parts of the client area must be redrawn. Eventually this will cause the system to call `OnPaint()`. If necessary, you can force an immediate update via `UpdateWindow()` but normally this is not needed. See [Synchronous and Asynchronous Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/synchronous-and-asynchronous-drawing).